# Finding $lim_{n \to \infty} ~ sup_{x>0}1_{(0,t_n)}(x)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

How to find $lim_{n \to \infty} ~ sup_{x>0}1_{(0,t_n)}(x)$. It is given that $t_n \geq 0, t_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and 1 denotes indicator function. It seems that limit should be simply zero but how to justify it? I'm facing this problem while trying to prove a result in banach spaces.

Answer (score 1):

For any $a>0$, $$\sup_{x>0} \mathbf 1_{(0,a)}(x)=1.$$ Hence, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{x>0} \mathbf 1_{(0,t_n)}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1 $$ not $0$.

On the other hand, $$\sup_{x>0}\lim_{n\to \infty}  \mathbf 1_{(0,t_n)}(x)=\sup_{x>0} 0 =0 $$which is maybe what you meant?

Comment: $ \displaystyle 1_{(0,a)}(x)=1$ only if $x \in (0,a)$. But here interval is shrinking to 0

Comment: Yes but you take the supremum first. So unless $(0,a)$ is empty the supremum of $\mathbf 1_{(0,a)}$ will be 1 independent of how close to 0 $a$ is.

Comment: The only way $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x>0} \mathbf 1 _{(0,t_n)} (x)=0$ is if there exists some $N$ such that $t_n=0$ for $n>N$ and this is only on a technicality because the interval will be empty